# How do I get my regex to translate the string I give it and not its own output?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, encryption, translation

So I'm trying to use Regex to create a kind of phonetic cipher; to translate individual characters or small groups of characters into other pre-assigned individual characters or small groups of characters.

```
Example Cipher:

ND = ONZ
ED = ANZ
EE = AAZ
AL = ORTH
IC = AMTH
CH = MAS
FF = UUG
LL = R
OO = UUZ
SS = OOG
TH = ASG
A = OTH
B = YTH
C = M
D = N
E = AZ
F = UG
G = ON
H = S
I = ATH
J = EZ
K = ETH
L = R
M = YZ
N = OZ
O = UZ
P = YN
Q = ITH
R = YG
S = OG
T = AG
U = AN
V = YN
W = L
X = IG
Y = UTH
Z = IZ
```

The problem I keep running into is that regex translates the string it just translated, so THE becomes ANIZAGOGSOOZAZ instead of ASGAZ. The process to get there is detailed below - CAPITALIZED LETTERS are what make it to the final product.

What's happening:

```
AN IZ AG OG S O OZ AZ

th = asg
     a = oth
         o = uz
             u = AN
             z = IZ
         t = AG
         h = s
             s = OG
     S
     g = On
         n = OZ
e = AZ
```

What I want to happen:

```
th = ASG
e = AZ
```

How do I prevent regex from translating its own outputs (or maybe from actually printing before everything is translated)?

The only real constraints here are that I need to be able to change the input and output values easily, and to create more or less of them. I am using Javascript Regex in Lingojam (https://lingojam.com/), so the input actually looks like:

```
/nd/g
/ed/g
/ee/g
/al/g
/ic/g
/ch/g
/ff/g
/ll/g
/oo/g
/ss/g
/th/g
/a/g
/b/g
/c/g
/d/g
/e/g
/f/g
/g/g
/h/g
/i/g
/j/g
/k/g
/l/g
/m/g
/n/g
/o/g
/p/g
/q/g
/r/g
/s/g
/t/g
/u/g
/v/g
/w/g
/x/g
/y/g
/z/g
```

Comment: Why do you think a regex should be used here?

Comment: You shouldn't replace the original string. You should generate a new one.

Comment: You probably need a parser instead. What should `IC` be translated into? `AMTH` or `ATHM`?

Comment: Who must be first? Two-letters strings or one-letter strings?

Answer (score 1):

Create a hash [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of strings to replacement strings. Using a Map guarantees the order of the keys. Create a regular expression by extracting the keys using [Map#keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys), [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) into an array, and [Array#join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) with pipe. use [String#replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a callback to encode the string.

**Note**: as noted [*skirtle* in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46248185/how-do-i-get-my-regex-to-translate-the-string-i-give-it-and-not-its-own-output/46248283?noredirect=1#comment79462348_46248283) - the order of the keys in the regular expression matters. /A|AL/ is not equivalent to /AL|A/, and you can't rely on 'greediness' to ensure the longer match takes precedence, it has to come earlier in the alternation.

```js
const hashMap = new Map([["ND","ONZ"],["ED","ANZ"],["EE","AAZ"],["AL","ORTH"],["IC","AMTH"],["CH","MAS"],["FF","UUG"],["LL","R"],["OO","UUZ"],["SS","OOG"],["TH","ASG"],["A","OTH"],["B","YTH"],["C","M"],["D","N"],["E","AZ"],["F","UG"],["G","ON"],["H","S"],["I","ATH"],["J","EZ"],["K","ETH"],["L","R"],["M","YZ"],["N","OZ"],["O","UZ"],["P","YN"],["Q","ITH"],["R","YG"],["S","OG"],["T","AG"],["U","AN"],["V","YN"],["W","L"],["X","IG"],["Y","UTH"],["Z","IZ"]]);

const pattern = new RegExp([...hashMap.keys()].join('|'), 'ig');

const result = 'THE'.replace(pattern, (str) => hashMap.get(str));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I think it's worth noting that ordering matters. `/A|AL/` is not equivalent to `/AL|A/`. You can't rely on 'greediness' to ensure the longer match takes precedence, it has to come earlier in the alternation.

Comment: @skirtle - thanks. I've switch to using a map to have a predictable key order, and noted your comment in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tokens = [ ['ND', 'ONZ'], ['ED', 'ANZ'], ['EE', 'AAZ'], ['AL', 'ORTH'], ['IC', 'AMTH'], ['CH', 'MAS'], ['FF', 'UUG'], ['LL', 'R'], ['OO', 'UUZ'], ['SS', 'OOG'], ['TH', 'ASG'], ['A', 'OTH'], ['B', 'YTH'], ['C', 'M'], ['D', 'N'], ['E', 'AZ'], ['F', 'UG'], ['G', 'ON'], ['H', 'S'], ['I', 'ATH'], ['J', 'EZ'], ['K', 'ETH'], ['L', 'R'], ['M', 'YZ'], ['N', 'OZ'], ['O', 'UZ'], ['P', 'YN'], ['Q', 'ITH'], ['R', 'YG'], ['S', 'OG'], ['T', 'AG'], ['U', 'AN'], ['V', 'YN'], ['W', 'L'], ['X', 'IG'], ['Y', 'UTH'], ['Z', 'IZ'] ];

function convert(str) {
  str = str.toUpperCase();
  var index = 0,
      result = "";
  while(index < str.length) {                        // while there is still letters in the string to process
    var tok = tokens.find(function(t) {              // find the next token (the one that matches the string str at the index index)
      return str.indexOf(t[0]) === index;
    });
    if(tok) {                                        // if there is a token
      result += tok[1];                              // add its equivalent string to result
      index += tok[0].length;                        // increment index to point at the next token start
    } else {                                         // if no token was found
      result += str.charAt(index);                   // then skip the current character (the one at the index index)
      index++;                                       // increment index to point ...
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(convert("THE"));
```